# input values cannot be saved into database

Tags: javascript, php

Here is my both php file where i am trying for a multiple star rating system. The code below is just for one category.The problem is the user can click on the star but the value being saved into the database is 0. The actual input value cannot be read or saved to the database. Is there any on click function need to be used or any other way to solve this. Thank You.

This is my ratings.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'pse2');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "<p>Connection Error</p>" 
    . "<p>" . mysqli_connect_error() . "</p>\n";
    die;
}

?>

<form method="post" action="insert_rating.php">
<div class="div">
  <p>Environment</p>
  <input type="hidden" id="environment1_hidden" value="1">
  <img src="star1.png" onmouseover="change(this.id);" id="environment1" class="environment">
  <input type="hidden" id="environment2_hidden" value="2">
  <img src="star1.png" onmouseover="change(this.id);" id="environment2" class="environment">
  <input type="hidden" id="environment3_hidden" value="3">
  <img src="star1.png" onmouseover="change(this.id);" id="environment3" class="environment">
  <input type="hidden" id="environment4_hidden" value="4">
  <img src="star1.png" onmouseover="change(this.id);" id="environment4" class="environment">
  <input type="hidden" id="environment5_hidden" value="5">
  <img src="star1.png" onmouseover="change(this.id);" id="environment5" class="environment">
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="environmentrating" id="environmentrating" value="0">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_rating">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my insert_rating.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_rating']))
{
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'pse2');


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "<p>Connection Error</p>" 
    . "<p>" . mysqli_connect_error() . "</p>\n";
    die;
 }

 $environment=$_POST['environmentrating'];

 $insertRating = "insert into rating (environment) values('$environment')";

 $success = mysqli_query($conn, $insertRating);

 $conn->close();
 }
```

Comment: how you change the value of environmentrating, where is js function?

Comment: debug your program .check $environment value .

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="environmentrating" id="environmentrating" value="0">` because `$_POST['environmentrating']` is set to 0?